# Съезжает карточка товара вправо при верстке на флексах

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Пытался задать размер блокам карточкам в процентах, но не выходит:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  height: 72px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.leftlogo {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.rightlogo {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.enter {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 78px;
  border: 2px solid #E0E0E0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input {
  font-style: Roboto;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 50;
  color: black;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: #ede6e6;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #ede6e6;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.forma {
  margin-top: 32px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.label {
  margin-top: 56px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.firstrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!--шапка-->
<header>
  <div class="leftlogo">
    <img src="logo.svg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="rightlogo">
    <button class="enter">
      Войти
    </button>
    <img src="basket.svg" alt="">
  </div>
</header>
<!--форма-->
<div class="forma">
  <p><input class="input" name="login" placeholder="Поиск по ресторанам и кухням"></p>
</div>

<!--Лэйбл ресторанов-->
<div class="label">
  <h1>Рестораны в Москве</h1>
</div>
<!--Галлерея Ресторанов-->
<div class="main">
  <div class="firstrow">
    <div class="macdonalds wid">
      <img class="magaz" src="1.jpg" alt="">
      <h3>Макдоналдс-Газетный</h2>
      <p>₽₽ • Бургеры</p>
      <p>25 - 35 мин</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dimsum wid">
      <img class="magaz" src="2.jpg" alt="">
      <h3>DimSum & Co — ЦДМ</h3>
      <p>₽ • Японская • Китайская • Азиатская</p>
      <p>40 - 50 мин</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dvijok wid">
      <img class="magaz" src="3.jpg" alt="">
      <h3>ДвижОК — Манежная</h3>
      <p>₽ • Американская • Европейская</p>
      <p>35 - 45 мин</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondrow"></div>
  <div class="thirdrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Покажите, что именно сейчас не так и как должно быть.

Comment: Я тоже не понял. Сделайте описание вашего вопроса лучше. Так что-бы и мы поняли тоже.